# Do CommCare Auto Case Closure case property filters overrule the Case Close field (days since updated)?

Tags: commcare

I want to set up an automatic case closure rule so that if the parent case has been flagged for closure (parent/hh_close_case = 'yes'), the child case will automatically close. This CommCare help site page on [Automatic Case Closure](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Automatically+Close+Cases) references the required Case Close field (where you specify the # of days after which the case should be closed if it hasn't been updated), and additional case property filters you can add.

I want my filter to be: parent/hh_close_case = 'yes', and I want the case to close immediately.

However, if I put X days in the Case Close field, will the case close only after X days AND after meeting the filter criteria? Or will it close as soon as it meets either the Case Close criteria OR the filter criteria?

Answer (score 2):

All of the criteria in the case close rule are ANDed together, so the case would only close if it has not been modified in X days AND all other conditions specified are true.